# Play two sounds with SoundPool

Tags: java, android, soundpool, android-imagebutton

I'm a newie to programming and I'm pretty sure that I'm making a dumb mistake here, but I'm stuck and can't manage to fix it.

The error that appears is the following:

Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'int[]', required: 'int'

This error appears almost at the end of the code, when trying to play the sounds. More specifically at:

```
spool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1f);
```

I'm pretty sure that this could be really easy to fix but I just couldn't do it. Can anyone help me fix it, please?

I decided to just post here the part where I'm having the issue; if someone would like to check the whole thing, it's right in the revisions.

```
if (rndm == 0) { //I'm just testing it with the horse sound
                             //right now, so if the random sound that is               
                             //played equals to zero, that's the horse sound
                final int[] soundId = new int[2];
                soundId[0] = spool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.el, 1); //"el" is the horse sound ID
                soundId[1] = spool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.applause, 1); //this is an applause clip I want to be played simultaneously with the horse sound
                ImageButton caballo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.caballo); //this is the horse ImageButton ID
                caballo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        spool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1f); //this is
                                                             //where I'm
                                                             //having the
                                                             //issue.
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Call `play()` twice, the first time with `soundId[0]` as the first argument, the second with `soundId[1]`.

Comment: @MikeM. Just a bit embarrassing. Thanks for the help. That made it.